# Meaning of bear and forbear?

Tags: meaning

> They will live the happiest life as soon as they have learnt and are ready to abide by the eternal lesson — that we are ***bound to bear and forbear*** and that life to every one must be a compromise. (VIVEKANANDA)

What does bear and forbear mean here ?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?  If you do, you will see what these words and the play between them mean.

Answer (score 1):

*To bear* means to accept and to endure here ([definition 3, Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bear)) and *to forbear* means to refrain, to control oneself ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/forbear)).

The proverb comes from a Stoicist motto *sustine et abstine*, to accept and endure external hardships and to abstain oneself from doing instinctive and emotional things in reaction.

In the sentence from the question, it means that "we are bound to accept and endure [life's challenges]".

> **Bear and forbear**
>
> Cf. Epictetus *Fragments* x. ἀνέχου καὶ ἀπέχου, ***be patient and endure***;
>   Erasmus Adages ii. vii. 13 *sustine et abstine*
>
> - **1573** T. TUSSER *Husbandry (rev. ed.)* II. 12V Both beare and forbeare, now and thenas ye may, then wench God a mercy [reward you], 
>     thy husband will say.
> - **1688** BUNYAN *Discourse of Building, &c. House of God* 53 To bear and forbear here, will tend to rest.
> - **1871** S. SMILES *Character* xi. The golden rule of married life is, ‘Bear and forbear’.
> - **1940** H. W. THOMPSON *Body, Boots & Britches* xix. You must take two bears two livewith you—Bear and Forbear.

[*The Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs (5 ed.)*](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199539536.001.0001/acref-9780199539536-e-102)

Comment: This shows that the expression is at least a loose collocation, but does not explain the meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the bold "be patient and endure" is the meaning.

Comment: @Matt E. Эллен I don't recognise the authority; dictionaries may be assumed to use synonyms, but merely showing an extract containing synonyms doesn't _license_. But of course, OP should have done the basic research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll add more information on the meaning. I am not sure what you mean by your second comment. Could you explain it more?

Comment: "What is the meaning of _forbear_?" would be unacceptable on ELU (and probably on ELL) as it is merely a matter of looking it up in a dictionary. Whether or not 'bear and forbear' is non-compositional (ie the string means something other than simply the sum of its parts), OP should at least include relevant definitions of the two words. See the Help Center.